# Jenkins : cloning remote git repository using https failed

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am configuring our project in jenkins to build after clone from remote https git repository. But got below error during cloning of the project.Any help to fix this issue is appreciated.

```
> git config --local credential.username myusername # timeout=10
> git config --local credential.helper store --file=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/git4065038663529705946.credentials # timeout=10
> git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://myusername@bitbucket-eng-sjc1.mycompany.com/bitbucket/scm/xxx/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes
> git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://myusername@bitbucket-eng-sjc1.mycompany.com/bitbucket/scm/xxx/myapp.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: 
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1740)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1476)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:63)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:314)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:506)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1046)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1086)
at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:495)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1278)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
ERROR: null
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Did you check the http/https proxy setting on machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem: `ERROR: Timeout after 10 minutes`. Test why id time outed.

Test connection, ping and authentication. Is server allowing connections from that domain/hostname/ip-range?

Comment: I can get the ping/authentication working with the server. Also am able to clone the project from terminal.

Comment: manual clone is working only if we use sudo from the jenkins workspace path.. without sudo, i am getting authentication error.. is this the problem? How to configure jenkins for this permission?

Comment: @Tutu sudo runs command as a root, not as your current user, and you should never do it. do you have ssh key for jenkins user added to your git repo?

Comment: We re using bitbucket server project repository and ssh key is not added to that server. Do you want me to create one and add?

Comment: Yes, you have to do it.

Comment: I have removed https and added ssh based connection setting, not i am able to clone the project. Thanks

Comment: @Tutu thanks for accepting the answer. I would suggest removing the root ssh-key from bitbucket too.

Comment: Update this post:
I'm using Mac and seeing the same issue. **I have a workaround.**

If you install Jenkins by using the pkg file, it will be in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/workspace`, you will have this trouble.

If you install Jenkins by using the war file, it will be in `/Users/[your_computer_name]/.jenkins/jobs/workspace`, you are good.

I don't what is the root cause since I'm very junior, but I hope this will unblock you.

> If you know the root cause, please comment here and help more people.

thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is any proxy setting done on system. Check if environment variable "**http_proxy**" or "**https_proxy**" is set. It might be the case that **http_proxy** environment variable it set, that's why you are able to clone/access the repository from command line.

In case proxy is set then you need to set the proxy in jenkins as well. 
Set http proxy on

```
"Jenkins -> Manage Jenkins -> Manage Plugins -> Advanced Tab".
```

Comment: No https/http proxy set in my system.. manual clone is working only if we use sudo from the jenkins workspace path.. without sudo, i am getting authentication error.. is this the problem? How to configure jenkins for this permission?

Comment: Run command "env" and "sudo env" and see if there is any difference in environment variable. Paste output of both commands here.

Comment: I have removed https and added ssh based connection setting, not i am able to clone the project. Thanks

Comment: Provide output of "env" and "sudo env" command. This seems to be related to some environment setting.